# ajax jquery context issue can not be solved

Tags: jquery

Despite of setting the context to "this" the intended methods can not be triggered. In the following code within the createNewTable function the "this.joinTable(data.tableId);" can not be fired despite of setting the context to this.

How I solove this issue. Please help.

```
var homePageKeycontroller = {

    currentIndex:0,
    tables: new Array("newGame"),

    init: function(){
        this.select();
    },

    select : function(){
        $(".box").css({
            background:"#FFAB25"
        });
        $("#"+this.tables[this.currentIndex]).css({
            background:"gray"
        });
    },
    next : function(){
        this.currentIndex++;
        if(this.currentIndex > this.tables.length-1)
            this.currentIndex = 0;
        this.select();
    },
    previous : function(){
        this.currentIndex--;
        if(this.currentIndex <= 0)
            this.currentIndex = 0;
        this.select();
    },
    createNewTable : function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://mywebiste.com/createAjaxTable",
            type:'post',
            dataType:'json',
            context:this,
            success:function(data){
                if(data.status == JsonStatus.OK){
                    alert("Table ID: "+data.tableId);
                    this.joinTable(data.tableId); // issue here
                }
            }
        });
    },
    handleUserChoice : function(){
        if(this.tables[this.currentIndex] ==='newGame'){
            this.createNewTable();
        }
    },
    joinTable : function(_tId){
        $.ajax({
            url:"http://mywebsite.com/JoinTable",
            type:'post',
            dataType:'json',
            data:{tableId:_tId},
            context:this,
            success:function(data){
                if(data.status == JsonStatus.OK){
                    this.showTable(); //issue here
                }
            }
        });
    },
    showTable : function(){
        $.ajax({
            url : 'http://mywebsite.com/showTable',
            success:function(data){
                DOM.mainCanvas.html(data);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: where you are referencing this it is localized to the success function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the jQuery API docs

> The **this** reference within all callbacks is the object in the **context** option passed to **$.ajax** in the settings; if **context** is not specified, **this** is a reference to the Ajax settings themselves.

So to get this working you can store a reference to **this** in a variable before the ajax call or call homePageKeyController.joinTable() directly inside the callback:

```
createNewTable : function(){
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://mywebiste.com/createAjaxTable",
        type:'post',
        dataType:'json',
        context:this,
        success:function(data){
            if(data.status == JsonStatus.OK){
                // Use self variable here since "this" belongs to callback
                // function context.
                // or call homePageKeyController.joinTable(data.tableId) instead.
                self.joinTable(data.tableId);
            }
        }
    });
},
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that inside 'success' method, 'this' keyword refers to ajax object containing 'success' method.

A simple workaround to fix this would be:

```
var homePageKeycontroller = {

  var that = this;

  createNewTable : function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://mywebiste.com/createAjaxTable",
        type:'post',
        dataType:'json',
        context:this,
        success:function(data){
            if(data.status == JsonStatus.OK){
                alert("Table ID: "+data.tableId);
                that.joinTable(data.tableId);
            }
        }
    });
},

joinTable : function(_tId){
    $.ajax({
        url:"http://mywebsite.com/JoinTable",
        type:'post',
        dataType:'json',
        data:{tableId:_tId},
        context:this,
        success:function(data){
            if(data.status == JsonStatus.OK){
                that.showTable();
            }
        }
    });
},
showTable : function(){
    $.ajax({
        url : 'http://mywebsite.com/showTable',
        success:function(data){
            DOM.mainCanvas.html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try the .done() syntax instead of :success. I have had these kind of issues with the success approach but never when using the done() approach.

```
createNewTable : function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://mywebiste.com/createAjaxTable",
            type:'post',
            dataType:'json',
            context:this
        }).done(function(data){
            if(data.status == JsonStatus.OK) {
                alert("Table ID: "+data.tableId);
                this.joinTable(data.tableId); // issue here
            }
        });
    },
```